# SQL command not properly ended execute immediate

Tags: sql

I'm trying to execute this code, but all the time i got an error message   "SQL command not properly ended on line 14"
line 14 is "execute immediate stmt;"

Can you help me?
Thaks.

```
declare 
    f varchar2(4);
    stmt varchar2(200);
    i number;
    e float;
    b float;
    d float;
    begin
    f:='f132';
    execute immediate 'select max('||f||') from testv2_2;' into e;
    execute immediate 'select min('||f||') from testv2_2;' into b;
    d:=(e-b)/20;
    stmt:='update testv2_2 set '||f||' =round('||f||'/'||d||');';
    execute immediate stmt;
    end;
```

Comment: have to checked that the SQL stmt runs correctly directly on the DB?

Comment: You should identify which DBMS you are using; it isn't self-evident.

Answer (score 5):

The semicolon (`;`) is the terminating character in [sqlplus](/questions/tagged/sqlplus) and other similar tools - it is not part of the SQL syntax. Hence, it should be removed. E.g.:

```
execute immediate 'select max('||f||') from testv2_2' into e;
execute immediate 'select min('||f||') from testv2_2' into b;
```

Comment: You're assuming it is Oracle — which is probably not a bad assumption.  Should the semi-colons in the `declare` statement be replaced by commas?